# React Native Expo - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo

When I execute an Expo project in the web browser with the command "expo start:web", I got this error.

How to solve this? Or is there any guide to run the expo project in the web browser?

[image]

Comment: does your code work with expo client?

Comment: Yes, it is working on Emulator. But when I open with browser, it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `react-native-maps` in your project and this package not supported for Web

Take a look at the [Platform Compatibility](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/)

Comment: Web doesn't support react-native-maps?
Then how to implement this expo project on browser? Is there any way?

Comment: currently, there is no maps package support for browser

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: In other words, you need to implement it yourself. Try implementing this section of the app separately!

Comment: How can I give you some link? that website was made by expo, And in there, map is working well.,

Comment: Share the link in comment, shall take a look

Comment: https://order.albohayra.com/location
Please check this site. This site was made by Expo. Then in this website, map is working well.